# What noise channel that is not coming from the control can lead to XY qubit rotations?

Tags: experimental-realization, decoherence, noise

In a semiclassical treatment, the noise Hamiltonian of a quantum system can be treated as a summation over its noise channels in the following way: 
$$\hat{H}_{\text{noise}}=\sum_{k}\beta_{k}\left(t\right)\hat{N}_{k}$$
where $\hat{N}_k$ is an operator indicating the noise axis in Hilbert space, and $\beta_k(t)$ is a classical noise field. Considering the case of a single qubit that is **not subjected to control fields**, the trivial noise channel  is $N_z = \sigma_z$ - fluctuations in the magnetic field in the environment of the qubit results in Zeeman splitting and therefore to an undesirable Z rotation.  However, I would like to know what physical process can lead to a noise channel in an orthogonal direction to the quantization axis (XY rotations)? To make it clear, all I am asking for is an example.

Comment: Given any physical channel for causing intentional rotation about X or Y, noise on that channel will cause undesired rotation about X or Y. What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: @DanielSank That's true, but I meant in the absence of a control channel.  Actually, I read the paragraph about "single qubit noise sources" in the documentation in the website of q-ctrl, and in their analysis they are taking into account 2 different noise channels: 1) Z rotation due to interaction of the qubit with the environment 2) X and Y rotations due to a noise in the control itself. I wondered why they are not taking into account XY rotation due to the interaction of the qubit with the environment?

Comment: Well if a qubit experiences X/Y rotations when subject to field $\beta$, then we usually introduce $\beta$ intentionally to do logic gates. If $\beta$ exists when we're not trying to do gates, then it's noise. So, I guess you're asking for a few examples, is that right?

Comment: @DanielSank Yes! Few examples will be great! I guess there are no massive such noise channels otherwise q-ctrl were taking it into consideration.